# Redis Time() command returns an empty result

Tags: redis

Our Redis server behaves strangely under high load. When calling the Time() command it will occasionally return an empty result (not an Exception, just empty result).

Is this an expected behavior when the server or network is overloaded?

Edit: info

```
    # Server
    redis_version:2.8.9
    redis_git_sha1:00000000
    redis_git_dirty:0
    redis_build_id:61e31fc3ea5bf6c
    redis_mode:standalone
    os:Linux 3.5.0-49-generic x86_64
    arch_bits:64
    multiplexing_api:epoll
    gcc_version:4.6.3
    process_id:31347
    run_id:be2da8cf9660eebd9c70149e0eb6c6e75f424eb2
    tcp_port:6379
    uptime_in_seconds:7774141
    uptime_in_days:89
    hz:10
    lru_clock:5927592
    config_file:/etc/redis/6379.conf

    # Clients
    connected_clients:2471
    client_longest_output_list:0
    client_biggest_input_buf:0
    blocked_clients:64

    # Memory
    used_memory:3162944192
    used_memory_human:2.95G
    used_memory_rss:3483242496
    used_memory_peak:16284341712
    used_memory_peak_human:15.17G
    used_memory_lua:797696
    mem_fragmentation_ratio:1.10
    mem_allocator:jemalloc-3.2.0

    # Persistence
    loading:0
    rdb_changes_since_last_save:812647
    rdb_bgsave_in_progress:0
    rdb_last_save_time:1415213438
    rdb_last_bgsave_status:ok
    rdb_last_bgsave_time_sec:22
    rdb_current_bgsave_time_sec:-1
    aof_enabled:0
    aof_rewrite_in_progress:0
    aof_rewrite_scheduled:0
    aof_last_rewrite_time_sec:-1
    aof_current_rewrite_time_sec:-1
    aof_last_bgrewrite_status:ok
    aof_last_write_status:ok

    # Stats
    total_connections_received:84090665
    total_commands_processed:15961550471
    instantaneous_ops_per_sec:2032
    rejected_connections:0
    sync_full:0
    sync_partial_ok:0
    sync_partial_err:0
    expired_keys:37013331
    evicted_keys:0
    keyspace_hits:3680528922
    keyspace_misses:91889146
    pubsub_channels:0
    pubsub_patterns:0
    latest_fork_usec:49438

    # Replication
    role:master
    connected_slaves:0
    master_repl_offset:0
    repl_backlog_active:0
    repl_backlog_size:1048576
    repl_backlog_first_byte_offset:0
    repl_backlog_histlen:0

    # CPU
    used_cpu_sys:61983.57
    used_cpu_user:925632.81
    used_cpu_sys_children:9471.61
    used_cpu_user_children:104999.56

    # Keyspace
    db0:keys=502,expires=187,avg_ttl=30590
    db1:keys=47290,expires=0,avg_ttl=0
```

Comment: Definitely not expected behavior :) Which version are you using? is there a way to reproduce this? It would be extremely helpful if you could provide more details (e.g INFO ALL) and open an issue in github.

Comment: @ItamarHaber I can't reproduce it, it happens randomly under heavy load.